# CSS styles not applying to element with class

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add separate properties to a text section on my website using the extra class name function. 
I tried using the custom css fields of my theme and those of visual composer but both have no effect. I'm running the startuply theme by Vivaco on WordPress 4.3.1

This is the code I'm using

```
about1 {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

This is what I want the text to look like - https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Is there any other way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `about1` ? A `class` or an `id` ? If it's a `class` you should use `.about1` and if it's an `id` you should use it as `#about1` .

Comment: It's about a class, It doesn't neither way with . and without.

Comment: Do you have a live url of the site ?

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: Yes, I managed to workaround the issue by customizing sections via Visual Composer plugin. I did not resolve the original issue of custom css not working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `.` before:

```
.about1 {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

And give this in HTML:

```
<div class="about1"><!-- No dot (.) here -->
```

Without anything, it is for tags. Eg:

```
h1 {}
p {}
```

With a `.`, it is for classes:

```
.newClass {}
.centerText {text-align: center;}
```

And with a `#`, it is for `id`s:

```
#btnSubmit {padding: 5px;}
```

In HTML:

```
<a class="newClass">Blah</a>
<div class="newClass centerText">Blah</div>
<input id="btnSubmit" name="submit" />
```

Comment: Okay, I did try with the . before, but it still did not work.

Where do I put the html?